# Java Filter JsonArray with Integer Array for parameter

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

My target is to filter `JSONArray` using `List` of `Integers` for parameter:

```
JSONObject record1 = new JSONObject();
record1.put("id", "44");
record1.put("name", "somename");
```

My current function that create new `JSONArray` and took id for parameter:

```
 private JSONArray modifyJsonArray(JSONArray array, final Integer param) throws JSONException {
        List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        mainJsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            mainJsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
            if (id == param) {
                jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }
        return new JSONArray(jsons);
    }
```

I want to pass a `List<Integer>` instead of `final Integer param`.

Comment: Ok and what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using two for loops:

```
  private JSONArray modifyJsonArray(JSONArray array, final List<Integer> param) throws JSONException {
    List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    mainJsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
        mainJsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < param.size(); j++){
            if (statusId == param.get(j)) {
                jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return new JSONArray(jsons);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, pass an arrray argument and put items:

```
 private JSONArray modifyJsonArray(JSONArray a,  int[] arr) throws JSONException {
        for(int i:arr){
            a.put(i);
        }
        return a;
}
```